# How to make a task not start until all resources are available in Microsoft Project?

Tags: ms-project

I have a project for knowledge transfer so most tasks have 3 resources assigned.  I want the KT to happen once, so all resources need to be available before the task can start.  How do I make this happen in MS Project?

Answer (score 1):

Set three milestone as predecessors to the KT package.  Resource 1 Ready, Resource 2 Ready, Resource 3 Ready.  When the resources are ready, you can indicated the actual finish date of the milestone.  If one is not ready, it would push the start of the successor package out.

Comment: The problem with this approach is people's vacations.  If I understand that would require me to manually review each person's vacations to create the milestones.

Comment: Yes, that's right.  You have no choice but to know the availability of the resources you are trying to schedule, human or otherwise.  If you cannot find the answers, then you have to assume and to a risk assessment and plan accordingly.